# Why is a website I didn't write on private IP?

Tags: html, web

As of late I started experimenting with website creation using html, JavaScript and CSS. I use node.js to be able to put the website on to the World Wide Web. Since I don't have a domain as of yet, I tried using my private IP but for some reason, some other website that I didn't write shows up. Could anyone explain what this is?

The following is the code for the website I found (This is the only file I found in sources):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>400</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='main' style='display:none'>
    <i><h2>Something error:</h2></i>
    <p>
      <h3>400</h3>
      <h3>
        <font color='red'>host not found.</font>
      </h3>
    </p>
    <p>Please check or <a href='javascript:location.reload()'>try again</a> later.</p>
    <hr>
    <div id='pb'>Generated by <a href='https://www.cdnbest.com/?code=400' target=_blank>kangle/3.5.21.4</a>.
    </div>
  </div>
  <script language='javascript'>
    var referer = escape(document.referrer);
    var url = escape(document.URL);
    var msg = 'host%20not%20found.';
    var hostname = '';
    var event_id = '';
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt language="javascript" src="https://error.kangleweb.net/?code=400"></scr' + 'ipt>');
  </script>
  <!-- padding for ie -->
  <!-- padding for ie -->
  <!-- padding for ie -->
  <!-- padding for ie -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>  <font color='red'>host not found.</font>
> ```

Your system appears to be configured to use a proxy server which doesn't have access to your private IP address.

When you ask the proxy server to get the website from your private IP address, it fails and tells you it can't find it.